# PHP doesn't work with shell_exec(), system() or passthru()

Tags: php, command-line, wamp

I am trying to read the most recent file from the folder. After finding the latest file, I'm reading it line by line and printing it on the barcode printer using barcode Overprinter software. This barcode printer is the default printer on my server.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $files = glob('C:\barcode\*.*');
    $files = array_combine($files, array_map('filectime', $files));
    arsort($files);
    echo key($files);  // for testing

    $handle = @fopen(key($files), "r");
    if ($handle) {
         while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
             echo $buffer; // for testing
              $retval=passthru("BarcodeGenerator.exe ".$buffer.",,Code128,0");
// based on http://www.free-barcode.com/CommandLineBarcode.htm
            echo $retval;
         }
            if (!feof($handle)) {
                echo "Error:\n";
         }
         fclose($handle);
    }
    ?>
```

The above command line runs fine in my command line prompt but it doesn't in php script.
The program hangs. Nothing happens. If I comment the passthru line, everything is fine. The program executes.

Here is what I've tried so far:

- Checked whether PHP is running in safe mode. It's not.
- Turned off Windows Firewall.
- I have run the command `calcs /g BarcodeGenerator.exe everyone:F`
- I have copied the executable and the related files to the wamp\www folder. the above code (bad idea, but I still did it) and redid calcs.
- I have changed the UAC settings to minimum
- No antivirus is currently running on my system.
- I've tried `system()`, `shell_exec()` and `exec()` too
- I've tried turning safe mode on and putting the above directory under `safe_mode_include_dir`
- I've tried replacing double quotes (`"`) with single quotes (`'`).
- I've tried giving the full path (`C:\\wamp\\www\\`)

The commands run fine in a command prompt.

So, is there any way to run the `shell_exec` command as administrator under PHP? It doesn't seem to want to run an executable at all (not only this one). I'm running `WAMP` on `Windows 7`.

For example, `shell_exec('dir')` works fine, but `shell_exec('java')` doesn't. Why not?

Comment: Does it hang, or does it produce an error you do not see (because error reporting isn't enabled) and are you waiting for output that'll never appear?

Comment: It just hangs until timeout. no error is produced. Error reporting is enabled.

Comment: Do you try look if the apache user have permission to execute ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't run any executables, like Java, this is definitely a permissions problem. The solution, while not recommended for a production server due to security, is to run your WAMP server as administrator.

See [this link](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,61302,71833) for details on how to do it.

Comment: Will this help as I've turned off UAC !! I'll still try

Comment: I understand why you said its not recommended on production. If Its not recommended then whats recommended..

Comment: There should be a way to allow the programs in question to run as the WAMP user, but that's further than I've attempted with WAMP.

Comment: just curious. why didn't calcs /g BarcodeGenerator.exe everyone:F work.

Comment: So I stopped wamp.. then opened command prompt in admin more and typed net user administrator /active:yes and then started wamp in the command line from the admin account.. It still didn't work..

Comment: Because it is still calling an executable program even though you are passing it through the calcs command.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12469/discussion-between-davidethell-and-ankur)