# Enable shell_exec() in wamp server

Tags: php, wamp

Recently I have passed one issue on wamp server..I need to use the `shell_exec()` function in PHP for running some external shell script (some checksum file) . But in my wamp server the function is disabled by default. I searched in google but I cant find out the solution. So I try to put that code in live server. But there's also the same problem. I contacted the technical person for that server but he said we cant enable shell_script. It is security violence.

**So only way is trying in wamp server... How to enable** `shell_exec()` or `exec()` ..?

Comment: is safe mode enabled? `shell_exec` is disabled in safe mode

Comment: Even if you manage to get it working on your WAMP server, how are you going to move it to your live server afterwards? How do you figure the function is disabled on your WAMP server? What did you try? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @Mob I've just noticed now that you're actually hijacking someone else's question, so my question regarding the live server is probably not relevant.

Comment: Actually, for me there's no moving to any live server. I just want it running on my windows box.

Comment: Is `shell_exec` even available on Windows?

Comment: Are you asking us to hack that server for you? Because going against server policy's is generally not a good idea. Though, if properly configured, this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 8):

The following line was the best I read to this problem: "You need to disable safe mode in the php.ini located in the \Apache2\bin folder, not the php folder. Restart Apache2 service right after to load the new settings."

The solution is:

1. stop all services from Wamp-Server and close the programm
2. Open .../wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.*.*/bin/php.ini
3. copy php.ini to desktop and open it
4. set **safe_mode_exec_dir** (line after = is empty, so IT IS ON!!!) set it off!
5. save
6. copy back to dir (maybe you need admin rights)
7. start wamp-server
8. enjoy exec() and co.

Comment: `set safe_mode_exec_dir (line after = is empty, so IT IS ON!!!) set it off!` ... i did not understand this ....my php.ini has `safe_mode_exec_dir = ` it is empty , do I need to type ON there?

Comment: how can i turn it off?

Comment: `safe_mode_exec_dir = off` is the answer, if it is not available in the php.ini just add a line, it works!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and tried a lot of solutions out there. What worked out for me was running XAMPP as Admin.

Answer (score 1):

Open your `php.ini` file used by wamp, find the `disable_functions` part, change it and restart the server.

Comment: Thanks for your replay..I already checked in php.ini file. the disable-functions is empty. No functions are disabled..

Comment: Sorry guys..Its all my problem..I was tried shell_exec() function 'ls -hal'. But its not working. Recently I just tried some other basic commands like  'cal' , 'date' ..Its working..Then I realized wamp is just giving us linux environment only. So we cant expect full linux command utilization. Actually I tried execute one 'c' file. Finally  I found solution. First we need to compile that 'c' file then only we can execute...This what I used..

<?php
$output = shell_exec('gcc -rdynamic -o mycompilefile prog.c'); 
$output = shell_exec('./mycompilefile'); 
print_r($output);

?>

Thanks for all..!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable safe mode in the php.ini located in the `\Apache2\bin` folder, not the php folder.

Restart Apache2 service right after to load the new settings.

Comment: Did you look into the php.ini in the Apache2 folder or not? **Not** the PHP folder, the Apache2 folder.

Comment: Check your phpinfo() to find the current loaded php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

Is not a "server problem". This configuration is not recommended. You must run the WAMP server in Administrator mode.

Here are some information: [PHP doesn't work with shell_exec(), system() or passthru()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005831/php-doesnt-work-with-shell-exec-system-or-passthru)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried backticks? (in case safemode is OFF)

```
`ls -hal`
```

Windows equivalent would be

```
`dir \AH`
```

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com Well, that's uncalled for. I did mention it. So RTFA to you, and the other comments on the question. On that note Mob did mention safemode is **OFF**

Answer (score 0):

Try using a WAMP server stack, which is clearly for development, like [WPN-XM](http://wpn-xm.org) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp.html).
Without any security limitations for the developer.
So you won't run into trouble, when executing system(), shell_exec(), passthrough().

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use these steps

1. Open wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin(doesn't matter apache version)
2. Open php.ini file in editor
3. Search for "***disable_functions***".
4. Remove ***exec*** and ***shell_exec*** from disable function
5. Restart all services.

Enjoy!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function _exec($cmd)
{
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /F /Create /TN _proc /TR "' . $cmd . '"" /SC DAILY /RU INTERACTIVE');
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "_proc"');
    shell_exec('SCHTASKS /DELETE /TN "_proc" /F');
}
_exec("mspaint.exe");
?>
```

Rather a hack, but if you're trying to start anything with a gui, or hangs, this is what I found that works.

Answer (score -2):

I just found a better explanation, but didn't tried it yet. Have a look - http://discussion.accuwebhost.com/linux-server/1096-how-enable-shell_exec-function-one-account.html

Comment: I don't think he has access to those configurations, else he would be able to enable it himself anyway.