# shell exec command not running ffmpeg

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, exec

I am writing this simple command to execute ffmpeg but shell_exec is not giving any result. Otherwise it is giving result with ls.

here is my code
{

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$output = shell_exec('ffmpeg -version');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

}

Comment: This isn't a system administration issue, it's a programming issue and such has a better home on [so]. You need to read the documentation on shell_exec (including the notes) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP with WAMP server, check below for enabling shell_exec in php

[Enable shell_exec() in wamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757891/enable-shell-exec-in-wamp-server)