# exec() PHP not working in browser but working ok in terminal

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to do the following in my php file:

```
exec("java -jar /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/Web/SimpleEncryption.jar hola", $output);
```

I get array(0) { }

If I execute php file.php in the terminal it works.

If I run

```
exec("whoami", $result);
```

I get Array ( [0] => daemon ) in the browser and Array ( [0] => dao ) in the terminal. dao=my user.

I don't know what permissions I have to give and how to give them.

Thanks

Comment: The webserver user (for example www-data for apache) does not have the permissions to execute shell commands.

Comment: Make sure the user `daemon` knows where to find `java`.

Comment: `java` probably isn't in the webserver's `$PATH`. Use the full path to the command.

Comment: Thanks, I added the Path to java... Now I get the following error: Error occurred during initialization of VM" [1]=> string(45) "Unable to load native library: libjava.jnilib
Someone said in another post to put this: exec('export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=""; /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version'); but it didn't work. Do you now how to solve it? I am using MAC

Answer (score 1):

It is probably that the username of the php server process is not your username. When you run it from the terminal you are logged in as dao, but the php process served up by your webserver is under a different username.     If you are using php-fpm the username is specified in the conf file.

Comment: I'm using XAMPP, where is the config file?

Comment: Now I have the same answer of whoami in the browser and in the terminal... but still doesn't work.

Comment: Depending on the version of php your using (< 5.3 I think ) you may have to disable safe mode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999673/how-to-enable-shell-exec-and-exec-on-php. Or you need to remove exec from the list of removed functions http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-lighttpd-phpini-disable-functions/

Comment: I have done both
safe_mode=Off
disable_functions=""
in php.ini

Comment: What is the output of `echo shell_exec("java -version");` in the browser?