# Cannot execute shell scripts in WAMP using shell_exec

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I am using `shell_exec()` to execute a command in my PHP code. but it is not working. I am using WAMP SERVER 3.0. Please help me to enable `shell_exec()` in my wamp.

This is already in my php.ini file:

```
disable_functions=""
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to enable shell\_exec and exec on php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999673/how-to-enable-shell-exec-and-exec-on-php)

Comment: Did you restart WAMP after editing the `php.ini` file?

Comment: I have not editted php.ini 

disable_functions="" 
It was already there in my php.ini