# Change user and run bash command on remote server via PHP shell_exec() function (Apache/Ubuntu)

Tags: php, apache, ssh, shell-exec

I am trying to get the output of a command. For now I'm just trying a simple "ls /home/."

```
$output = shell_exec("sudo -u myusername ssh remote_server ls /home/");

echo json_encode($output);
```

This is being called from an Ajax call, and when I log the data returned, I get "null." In /var/log/apache2/error.log, I'm getting:

```
  sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Since the php script is going to run as www-data, I have this in my sudoers file:

```
www-data ALL= NOPASSWD:/var/www/path/to/the/file.php
```

What am I doing wrong? I just need to return data from a command on a remote server as www-data.

I tried appending '2>&1' to the command as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56571689/how-to-execute-java-command-from-php-page-with-shell-exec-function) answer suggested, but that did not work. However, it did change my console output from

```
null
```

to

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an RSA key pair for www-data, and put my id_rsa.pub on the remote machine. That fixed it.