# SSH and exec() users differ

Tags: php, cron, exec, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have a [Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/) instance in AWS, and it's a LAMP stack. Previously, I (or [bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/), not sure) created a cron for SSL. It looks something like this:

```
0 0 * * * sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --path /o...
```

If I connect via SSH and run `crontab -l`, I get the following output (the second cron is for test purposes):

```
0 0 * * * sudo /opt/bitnami/letsencrypt/lego --path /o...

* * * * * sudo /usr/bin/touch /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/.htaccess
```

Now, I'm thinking about adding more cron jobs that are related to the app. Adding cron jobs manually (via SSH) is tedious. I want to be able to do this in the UI. I'm saying this because I've seen this done (e.g. in DirectAdmin, Plesk Panel, WHMCS, etc.)

So I started searching for ways to view/edit/delete cron jobs in the PHP. The [idea](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm) seems simple. Get the current cron jobs (`crontabs -l`), parse and modify them, and load it back (`crontabs file`). So I tried to get the current cron jobs (in a PHP file, from the browser), but failed:

```
exec("crontab -l", $crons);
exec("crontab -u bitnami -l", $crons_bitnami);

exec("sudo crontab -l", $sudo_crons);
exec("sudo crontab -u bitnami -l", $sudo_crons_bitnami);

var_dump(exec("whoami")); // daemon
var_dump(shell_exec("crontab -l")); // NULL

var_dump($crons);         // array(0) { }
var_dump($crons_bitnami); // array(0) { }

var_dump($sudo_crons);         // array(0) { }
var_dump($sudo_crons_bitnami); // array(0) { }
```

I get empty results. I get the two cron jobs that I added if I run `crontabs -l` in the SSH, but this doesn't work in the PHP. So I checked the users. If I type `whoami` in SSH, I get `bitnami`. In PHP, it returns `daemon`. I searched more and figured out that each user has its own cron jobs. In SSH, I'm the user `bitnami` and it has two cron jobs. Why am I `daemon` in PHP? Is that the reason I'm getting an empty result? If so, can/how do I change it?

I tested the same code on other servers, and I seem to get correct results. The user is not `daemon` and I can see the cron jobs. So this might be Lightsail/bitnami related. Nevertheless, is there anything that I can do to fix it?

Comment: Did you try using the full path to crontab e.g. (`/usr/bin/crontab -u bitnami -l`). This has tripped me up in the past . Check where crontab  located with `which crontab`.

Comment: @Jamie_D Nope, I did not. But I tested it just now, and it didn't work. I've seen similar warnings/suggestion (using full path), but didn't think it'd help. I wish it was that simple :)

Comment: You should check that exec function is not disabled in your php.ini file:  [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999673/how-to-enable-shell-exec-and-exec-on-php)

Comment: How do you run `whoami` in PHP?  Be more specific.

Comment: @AbraCadaver `var_dump(exec("whoami"))`. It's in the example.

Comment: From the command line logged in SSH or that is in a page you access with a browser?  That's what I meant by specific.

Comment: I ran the `var_dump(exec("whoami"))` in a page (on the browser).

Comment: Now that you mention it, I tried to run it in SSH, that is `php -a`, and then `var_dump(exec("whoami"));`. It returned `bitnami`, which is correct. Weird?

Comment: I was going to suggest that. The crontab in your browser is not the same as the one you run under SSH (hence the NULL crontab). The way around this would be to change the user in you PHP file (never tried this), or to enter the cron jobs under the daemon user

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Linux, so all I could come up with to look for inconsistencies (maybe related to `daemon`). I've found this. `htdocs` folder's owner and group differs, and it includes `daemon`. Could that be related to the problem? [FileZilla screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/SNckhWe.png)

Comment: The webserveer process runs as `daemon`.  Virtually all webservers will run as some limited user such as as `nobody` `www-data` or something else. most likely `daemon` will need sudo access to crontab as `bitnami`.

Comment: I tried to add a cron job in PHP file and see the result in SSH (`sudo crontab -u daemon -l`), but then I got `The user daemon cannot use this program (crontab)`. Next, I checked `/etc/cron.deny` and `daemon` was listed there... This is really frustrating. Am I not allowed to control crontab from PHP? :\

Comment: I decided to remove `daemon` from `/etc/cron.deny`. I still can't add cron in the PHP file. I can add cron in SSH using `sudo crontab -u daemon -e`, but the cron doesn't work/tick. Also, now I can view the crons in the PHP file using only `crontab -l` or `crontab -u daemon -l`. Any other combination doesn't work. Since I can't add and the cron doesn't work, viewing doesn't matter... This sucks. I guess I'm going to have to contact AWS and/or bitnami.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. I just removed the daemon user from the `/etc/cron.deny` file as you mentioned and manually added a new entry in the cron file for daemon `* * * * * date >> /tmp/date.txt`. After waiting one minute, I confirmed that the date.txt file was created and it included the date command output information. Please note that the daemon user has no home folder or shell configured by default (`/etc/passwd`) and that can be the issue you are running into when running commands.

Comment: @JotaMartos Thanks for the reply. Your example worked. I'd done my test with `touch` and it didn't work. I guess it was because the file it tried to touch belonged to `bitnami`, not to `daemon`. Permission issues :\ I tried to modify a text file (counter.txt) using cron, but then again, file is created by/belongs to `bitnami`; `daemon` can't access it. What do I do? Change permission/ownership? Everytime? I tried to change the PHP user by changing `daemon` to `bitnami` in `/opt/bitnami/php/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf.default`, but didn't work. Why? There should be a documentation for this...

Comment: Apache and PHP-FPM work using the daemon user due to security reasons. If you are editing one file of your application, you need to ensure that file can be written by the daemon user/group. `sudo chown bitnami:daemon -R /path/to/your/app/directory; sudo chmod g+w -R /path/to/your/app/directory`. Regarding the documentation, we have [a guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/administration/create-custom-application-php/) that explains how to deploy a custom PHP app on top of LAMP and how to configure the permissions.